# How do I feed CD audio tracks into an ALSA-driven sound output device?

Tags: raspbian, alsa, cd-rom

I'm using a USB CD/DVD drive without built-in sound decoder and controlling it via ALSA, which already works. The host is a Raspberry Pi 3B with the current Raspbian. Here is the corresponding config file:

```sh
pi@autoradio:/etc $ cat asound.conf
pcm.dmixer {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_perm 0666
    slave {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        rate 192000
        format S32_LE
        channels 2 
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.dsnooper {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2048
    ipc_perm 0666 
    slave 
    {
        pcm "hw:0,0"
        period_time 0
        period_size 1024
        buffer_size 4096
        rate 192000
        format S32_LE
        channels 2 
    }
    bindings {
        0 0
        1 1
    }
}

pcm.duplex {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "dmixer"
    capture.pcm "dsnooper"
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex"
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

To read the music from CD-DA, I'm gonna use the [CDIO++ library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libcdio/). Its `cd-info` utility recognises both the drive, and the audio CD:

```sh
pi@autoradio:/etc $ cd-info
cd-info version 2.1.0 armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf

CD location   : /dev/cdrom
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: IOCTL

Vendor                      : MATSHITA
Model                       : CD-RW  CW-8124  
Revision                    : DA0D
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : No
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : No
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: CD-DA
```

I've already got [some code to send the PCM data to the sound card](https://gist.github.com/ghedo/963382/815c98d1ba0eda1b486eb9d80d9a91a81d995283) and some insight regarding the (rather poorly documented) CDIO API (I know that the [`readSectors()`](https://github.com/xbmc/libcdio/blob/master/include/cdio%2B%2B/read.hpp#L82) method is used for reading sound data from the CD sector after sector), but not really a clue on how to hand over the data from the CD-DA input to the ALSA output routine correctly.

Please nopte that `mplayer` is off-limits to me as this routine will be a part of a larger solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Does the different block size of an audio CD (2,352 bytes) and of the sound output (910 bytes, at least in my particular case) matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CD audio data is just two channels of little-endian 16-bit samples at 44.1 kHz.

If you output the data to the standard output, you can pipe it into your sound-playing program, or `aplay`:

```
./my-read-cdda | ./play 44100 2 99999
./my-read-cdda | aplay --file-type raw --format cd
```

If you want to do everything in a single program, replace the `read(0, ...)` with `readSectors()`. (The buffer size does not need to have any relation with ALSA's period size or buffer size.)

Comment: OK, thank you. I've now got another question you can find in my original post.